# Does easyUI support setting request header?

Tags: javascript, jquery-easyui

I was using easyUI components (datagrid, form, input) and I found that setting request header is not supported in easyUI.

But after I modified $.ajaxSetup() as below

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
        var token = "sth.";
        var header = "sth.";
        if(token.length > 0 && header.length > 0){
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        }
    }
```

Request headers could be setted in datagrid, but some other objects like  input/combobox which request remote data in data-options attribute, didn't work.

```
   <input class="easyui-combobox" editable="false"
               data-options="valueField:'id',textField:'name', method:'get', url:'cluster/list.json'"/>
```

Could anyone help me to add request header in **data-options** or Does easyUI support setting headers feature?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by upgrade easyUI to 1.4 which has the feature of submitting form with Ajax.

Refer to: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/form.php